# Why is the order of multiple `for` list comprehension the way it is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I know the right way to have multiple `for` in a nested list comprehension is as follows (Python 3):

```
lista = [[[1,2],[3],[4,5,6]],[[7],[8,9]]]

flatlista = [i for k in lista for j in k for i in j]
# results with [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But my natural language instincts strongly object. I would have (wrongly) expected the code to be:

```
flatlista = [i for i in j for j in k for k in lista]
```

The wrong version sounds almost like English and is read in one stream left to right. The correct version requires some nested reading skills skipping left and right to encompass the meaning.

Why is this syntax as it is? Why was the language built this way?

Comment: I actually see it the very opposite. The way it is implemented, you read from left to right, and (apart from the comprehension body `i`) never have to look on the right to see what’s available. You write `for k in lista` and you know you have `k` available, so you do `for j in k` next and know you have `j` available etc. In your version, you actually have to read from the right to the left to go from the outside to the inside.

Comment: That being said, I can see your confusion. For me, my initial expectations also were that it would read from the outside to the inside, just because many programming languages would work like that.

Comment: I agree with OP that the second ordering presented is more intuitive. For me, this part of the Python programming language violates the principle of least surprise, unusual for Python!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because that's what [PEP 202 -- *List Comprehensions*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) set it to. The PEP doesn't quite motivate why however, as it was created as an afterthought; the discussion had taken place on the development lists years before the PEP was created, or even the PEP *process* had been created.

First of all, the order mirrors the order you'd nest `for` loops and `if` statements in Python code:

```
for k in lista:
    for j in k:
        for i in j:
```

This makes it very natural if you are already used to *that* ordering.

Looking at the [very first discussions about the feature](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/comp.lang.python/gmzq_lMhtbc/cEMzmGs1FAkJ) there appears to be precedent in other languages for the ordering. And indeed, [Haskell has the same ordering](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension): *each successive generator refines the results of the previous generator*.

Certainly, at some point Tim Peters (the originator of the proposal) states that the order used today is obvious to *him*, see [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/gmzq_lMhtbc/rYAzT196oqkJ):

> I've posted my proposed translation into today's Python a few times already,
>   with the intent that it be taken literally, not suggestively.  This nests
>   "for" loops with the leftmost outermost, so nails everything about the
>   ordering semantics at all levels.  Why that's become a debating point at all
>   levels is beyond me .

Comment: Ahh, the visual makes it very clear and easy to remember, thanks @martijn pieters!

Answer (score 2):

Just remember the famous line from Casablanca: "Of all the gin joints in all the towns in all the world..."  And then remember that the Python equivalent is *backwards* from that.

```py
[ginjoint for town in world for ginjoint in town]
```

Because who wants their programming language to sound like the greatest movie of all time?

Answer (score 0):

Just found your post as i was wondering the same

Well yes - seems like it should be read like a flatten for loop

```
paragraph = ["hi stackoverflow devs!", "i know there is a comment", "that comment is not the same"]
letters = []

for sentence in paragraph:
    for word in sentence.split(" "): 
        if word != "comment":
            for letter in word:
                letters.append(letter)

letters = [letter for sentence in paragraph for word in sentence.split(" ") if word != "comment" for letter in word]

print(letters)
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35790923)